# How to hide table cells and make another cell fill the vacated space

Tags: css, html

Suppose I have a table like so:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th colspan="3">Type Info</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeA">
         <td><input name="type[0]" /></td>
         <td class="group1"><input name="A[0]" disabled /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="B[0]" disabled /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="C[0]" disabled /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeB">
         <td><input name="type[1]" /></td>
         <td class="group1"><input name="A[1]" /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="B[1]" disabled /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="C[1]" disabled /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeC">
         <td><input name="type[2]" /></td>
         <td class="group1"><input name="A[2]" disabled /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="B[2]" /></td>
         <td class="group2"><input name="C[2]" /></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

There are certain data combinations that are not valid, so we disable the inputs. In this case, I believe the data makes semantic sense as a table - I am not just using a table for layout purposes.

What I would like to do is hide the disabled cells, and have the cells with the non-disabled elements fill the space formerly taken by the now hidden cells.

I can accomplish the hiding with the following css:

```
.typeA .group1, .typeA .group2 {
    display:none;
}

.typeB .group2 {
   display:none;
}

.typeC .group1 {
    display:none;
}
```

However, this gives me:

```
|_____Type____|____________,__Type Info__,__________|
|_____________|
|_____________|____________|
|_____________|____________|_____________|
```

What I want is:

```
|_____Type____|____________,__Type Info__,__________|
|_____________|
|_____________|____________,_____________,__________|
|_____________|____________,_____________|__________|
```

(`|` represent cell boundaries, `,` represents where a single cell crosses the layout cell boundaries.

What css can I use to get the desired `td` to expand to fill the horizontal space vacated by the hidden `td` elements?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to do this using solely CSS.  It seems that to accomplish what I want, the html structure has to be modified in one way or another.

I found two options:

1. Do a row by row modification of the table structure, removing hidden `td` elements and adding appropriate `colspan` attributes to the visible `td` elements
2. Place all of the "group1" and "group2" inputs in the *same* cell, with additional `div` structures that can be styled as table cells.

For the second option, e.g.

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Type Info</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeA">
         <td><input name="type[0]" /></td>
     <td>
        <div class="group1">
            <input name="A[0]" />
        </div>
        <div class="group2">
            <div>
                <input name="B[0]" />
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div>
                <input name="C[0]" class="staticSize" />
            </div>
    </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeB">
         <td><input name="type[1]" /></td>
     <td>
        <div class="group1">
            <input name="A[1]" />
        </div>
        <div class="group2">
            <div>
                <input name="B[1]" />
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div>
                <input name="C[1]" class="staticSize" />
            </div>
    </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="typeC">
         <td><input name="type[2]" /></td>
     <td>
        <div class="group1">
            <input name="A[2]" />
        </div>
        <div class="group2">
            <div>
                <input name="B[2]" />
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div>
                <input name="C[2]" class="staticSize" />
            </div>
    </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

For the second option css, something like the following:

```
table {
    width:100%;
}

.typeA .group1, .typeA .group2 {
    display:none;
}

.typeB .group2 {
   display:none;
}

.typeC .group1 {
    display:none;
}

.typeC div.group2 {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.typeC div.group2>div {
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}

input:not(.staticSize) {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
visibility: hidden;
```

That should keep it in the layout.

Comment: That does indeed keep it in the layout, but doesn't quite do everything I'm asking for - it doesn't make the visible cell expand to fill the space occupied by the hidden cells.